# как просмотреть «реакцию» браузера на ответы с http-ошибкой?

Tags: php, apache

Хочу на локальном сервере симулировать ошибку 500.

Как это правильно делается?

Пробовал просто устанавливать заголовки, но в браузер совершенно ничего не выводилось.

Comment: Так вы ничего браузеру не посылаете, вот и пусто. На 500ую можно картинку послать, например, `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error'); echo "<image src='$imageUrl' style='width: 100%' />";` - будет она отображаться. В консоли разработчика смотрите, сейчас ваша ошибка только там.

Comment: если скрипт запустить из консоли то он возвратит только igor@igor-H81M-S2V:/var/www/trysome$ php -f error500.php 
<image src='http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/documentation/SIGPro_Settings_Closed.png' style='width: 100%' />igor@igor-H81M-S2V:/var/www/trysome$ 
,             об ошибке там нету информации. Или я как то делаю не так?

Comment: Для того, чтобы на вопрос можно было ответить, добавьте весь относящийся к проблеме код и сообщения об ошибках в сам вопрос. [ask], [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Вы не поняли, я имел ввиду следующее: открываете барузер (например, Chrome), там открываете консоль разработчика (для хрома она открывается по F12), в консоли открываете закладку "сеть" (или аналогичное). После этого открываете вашу страничку. В консоли будет показано обращение к серверу и ответ сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью функции [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-response-code.php)

```
// например,
http_response_code(500);
// или
http_response_code(404);
```

Comment: пожалуйста как для чайника))) я пробывал эту функцию может не разобрался как работает. Вот что пробывал      <?php
http_response_code(500);

Comment: @IgorKalamurda, вы же хотели увидеть реакцию браузера, вот и откройте консоль, где увидите его реакцию ))

Comment: Через браузер открывал, и через консоль запускал - браузер чист, консоль чиста. Наденьте очки мне )))

Comment: Не запускать через консоль, а смотреть результат. В Chrome будет что-то в этом роде: _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)_ , в FF - _GET http://site.com/ [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4мс]_

P.S. Если смотрите в Chrome, то поставьте галочку на "**Preserve Log**"

Comment: @Deonis, ТС не знает про какую консоль говорим, я выше написал как к ней доступ получить, надеюсь найдет ее

Comment: понял о какой вы консоли говорите)) Спасибо